# Get classes of parameters to method call (ExecutableElement) inside processor at compile time

Tags: java

I have a class, inside which I have a method with a custom annotation being handled at compile time using a processor.

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    @ListenFor
    public void handleRequest(Object something, String other) {

    }
}
```

I would like to validate the class of the second argument the method is expecting and make sure it is `String`.

Inside the processor, I get the executable element of the method and get the parameters from it as VariableElements:

```
ExecutableElement exeElement = (ExecutableElement) e;

List<? extends VariableElement> params = exeElement.getParameters();
```

How can I get the class of the second argument (String other) at compile time inside the processor, so I can compare it to the `String` class and validate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you operate at compile-time, you cannot necessarily rely on [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instances. Instead, there is another representation for compile-time types, called [`TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html).

We can get the `TypeMirror` of an [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html) through [`Element#asType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType()). There is no way to obtain a `Class` object from a `TypeMirror` for the aforementioned reason. In order to check whether the second argument is a `String`, we need to convert `String.class` into a `TypeMirror`. Method [`Elements#getTypeElement(CharSequence name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getTypeElement(java.lang.CharSequence)) gives us a `TypeMirror`, given a cannonical name. We can get the canonical name of a `Class` instance through [`Class#getCanonicalName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName()).

This leads to the following code:

```
// assuming the processingEnvironment got passed to the method.
// It is a good idea to store the elementUtil somewhere
// globally accessible during annotation processing.
Elements elementUtils = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
...
TypeMirror stringType =
    elementUtils.getTypeElement(String.class.getCanonicalName()).asType();
...
ExecutableElement exeElement = (ExecutableElement) e;
List<? extends VariableElement> params = exeElement.getParameters();
TypeMirror secondArgumentType = params.get(1).asType();

// I find the explicit version has a less cognitive complexity. Feel free to change it.
if (secondArgumentType.equals(stringType) == false) { 
    // TODO: halt and catch fire!
}

// from here on, you can be certain that the second argument is a String.
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just a note, `getElementUtils()` is not a static method, should probably be called in the init() method, assigning its result to a field variable, and that field variable should be used in process(). Also typeUtils isn't really needed in this case.

Comment: `TypeMirror stringType = elementUtils.getTypeElement(String.class.getCanonicalName());` won't type-check, an `asType()` call needs to be added

Comment: @AmanSingh thank you for the comments. I edited my answer accordingly.